# Vector representation of the Virasoro Algebra

Tags: conformal-field-theory, representation-theory, vector-fields, lie-algebra

The Witt algebra is defined by the following Lie Bracket :

$$
[l_n,l_m]=(n-m)l_{(n+m)}.
$$

One representation can be obtained by an algebra of conformal killing vectors of Minkowski space:
$$
ds^2 = -dt^2+dx^2 = d(x-t)d(x+t)=dw_+dw_-
$$

By defining:
$$
\rho(l_n) = (w_+)^{n+1} \partial_{w_+}.
$$

One can verify that with the usual Lie bracket between two vectors we have:

$$
[\rho(l_n),\rho(l_m)] = (n-m)\rho(l_{n+m}).
$$
In fact, Minkowski space supports two copies of the representation of the Witt algebra, by replacing $w_+$ by $w_-$. This is the conformal algebra.

The Witt algebra admits also a non-trivial central extention (which is essential for conformal field theories), known as the Virasoro algebra:

$$
[l_n,l_m] = (n-m)l_{(n+m)} +\frac{c}{12} (n^3-n)\delta_{n+m,0}.
$$

Is there a representation similar to the Witt one, in the case of the Virasoro algebra? I haven't seen any resource that provided such a representation. If it doesn't exist, is there a fundamental reason why it doesn't?

Comment: So the [original one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra_extension#Bosonic_open_strings) is unsatisfactory?

Comment: In the representation you linked the commutators are realised as commutators of quantum operators. I would like to know if there is a representation of the algebra where the commutators are Lie Brackets of vector fields, or a modification of these. I should have made that clearer in my question, even though the question still isn't very precise

Comment: There's no non-zero vector field that commutes with every holomorphic vector field. This is why the central charge is often referred to as a quantum or anomalous term.

Comment: I see, that's what I suspected. Thanks for the answer !